# PHP imagick annotate setFont exceeds max execution time

Tags: php, macos, imagemagick, imagick

Im tryin to write some text to an image using php imagick.
It runs okay on my server, but i have a problem running it on my macbook.

the code:

```
/* Text to write */
$text = "Hello World!";

/* Create Imagick objects */
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$color = new ImagickPixel('#000000');
$background = new ImagickPixel('none'); // Transparent

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Arial');
$draw->setFontSize(50);
$draw->setFillColor($color);
$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
$draw->setTextAntialias(true);

/* Get font metrics */
$metrics = $image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $text);

/* Create text */
$draw->annotation(0, $metrics['ascender'], $text);

/* Create image */
$image->newImage($metrics['textWidth'], $metrics['textHeight'], $background);
$image->setImageFormat('png');
$image->drawImage($draw);

/* Save image */
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $image;
```

When i run this on  my macbook, the processor gets stuck at at 100%, and the process is killed in 30 seconds with the message: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in.....on line 13, which is the one with $draw->setFont();

Thank you for your responses...

Comment: Are the versions of image magick the same on your server and on your macbook?

Comment: Macbook module ver: 3.0.1, im ver: 6.5.7-0, server module: 2.1.1-rc1, im: 6.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Guess:** Arial is not available on your system or provide a complete path for the font to `setFont()`

```
$draw->setFont('/path/to/ARIALB.ttf');
```

Comment: Have you tried a different font other than Arial? Is Arial.ttf a copy of the server's TTF file or the default system font for mac?

Comment: Yes, i have tried also a different font, and it was the default one, but i updated macports, and then all the packages, reinstalled imagick via pecl, and it works like a charm now :) the only questions is, if it's okay to have the rc1, and 6.3.7 on the server, because there is no easy way to update this... it's the newest package in the debian lenny aptitude...